# JSON key value being sent with enclosing single quotes from web form to express and bodyParser

Tags: node.js, json, express, hcaptcha

I am sending a username, password and the h-captcha-response token to express via a login form. The username and password are being sent fine from the form, without single quotes, the h-captcha-response ( which is formulated by hcaptcha and sent back to the web form and is sent also) is being sent with enclosing single quotes and the hcaptcha middleware ( express-hcaptcha ) sees no token. Response from the middleware is ....

`Error: bad request - no token provided in body`

I am using https://github.com/vastus/express-hcaptcha

When I dump the req I am seeing that the h-captcha-response is enclosed in single quotes. I believe this may have to do with the form input that is being sent to express is not being set to application/json but that’s a guess since I am new to node/express.

The applicable part of the req dump is below and followed by the node/express info. Can someone point me in the correct direction ? Many thanks JW

req dump ( via console.log )

```
————-
<snip>
….
….
body:
   { username: ‘xxxx’,
     password: ‘xxxx’,
     'h-captcha-response': ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxxx’ },
  _body: true,
  length: undefined,
….
….
<snip>
```

Appropriate parts of the js file
—————

```
const http = require('http');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const hcaptcha = require('express-hcaptcha');

//hcaptcha secret key
const SECRET = “xxxxxx”; 

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
…..<snip>
});

const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set("view engine","hbs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));


//create app server
var server = app.listen(3000,  "0.0.0.0", function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
});

app.post('/verify', hcaptcha.middleware.validate(SECRET), (req, res) => {
  res.json({message: 'verified!', hcaptcha: req.hcaptcha});
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log`ging the `h-captcha-response`?

Comment: That's what the req dump is ( voted u up.. thanks! ) .... I'll clarify in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Can you reformat the code? It's hard to read.

Comment: can you rename your 'h-captcha-response' to "token" and see if it works? if you see https://github.com/vastus/express-hcaptcha/blob/master/index.js validate method, it get token from req.body.token. so it should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks Illesh. Renaming to token doesn't fix the issue. I might just go ahead and install axios to send the call manually.

Comment: The single quotes is just how node prints a string inside an object. If you `console.log(req.body['hcaptcha-response'])` you won't see them.

Comment: @leitning, I learned something tremendous from your response. I had been trying to find a way to access the h-captcha-response var when all I knew was req.body.xxx way and not the way to access via the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key `'h-captcha-response'` is enclosed in quotes because that's the only way you can create an object key containing special characters (`-` in this case) in javascript:

```js
const bad = { a-b: '' }
            // ^ Parsing error: unexpected token, expected ","

const good = { 'a-b': '' } // no error
```

And while node is not creating an object here but just logging it into the console it still respects common js syntax.

As for the error: `Error: bad request - no token provided in body`.
It's happening because `express-hcaptcha` middleware [expects the field named `token`](https://github.com/vastus/express-hcaptcha/blob/master/index.js#L9). If the field as absent or evaluated to the [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value you're getting the [error](https://github.com/vastus/express-hcaptcha/blob/master/index.js#L13) you can observe now.

If you're sending data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then to fix the issue you have to change the `name` attribute of the captcha field in your html form from `h-captcha-response` to `token`.

If you're sending data as `json` then do the same renaming to the key of the sending json object.

Comment: This is tremendously helpful. Selected as answer.